# Laravel "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel and i have a problem with tags after I update my code for tags. When I click on a tag I face this problem:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() (View: C:\blog\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)

My code in controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Tag;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    if(request('tag'))
    {
        $articles = Tag::where('name', request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->articles;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $articles = Article::latest()->get();
    }
    return view ('articles.index',['articles' => $articles]);
}
```

The show page

```
@foreach ($articles as $article )
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="/articles/{{$article->id}}">
                            {!! $article->title !!}
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <p>
                <img src="/images/banner.jpg" alt="" class="image image-full"/>
                </p>

                {!! $article->exceprt!!}
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

This is the Tag eloquent:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
}
```

Comment: `Log::info($articles);` inside of your controller before your return statement, and check your log in `storage/logs` to see what it contains. Most likely it is not a collection of items.

Comment: Here is my controller 

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Tag;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if(request('tag'))
        {
            $articles = Tag::where('name', request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->articles;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $articles = Article::latest()->get();
        }
        return view ('articles.index',['articles' => $articles]);
    }

Comment: please write `dd($articles);` before `return view ('articles.index',['articles' => $articles]);` and add the response in your question

Comment: Everything was working before i add the tags, it was showing the articles

Comment: do you have your relationship `articles()` in place in your `Tag` model?

Comment: when i press a tag it give me null

Comment: when i press the articles page it give me this
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#274 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▶]
}

Comment: yes i have a relationship, i will update the question

Comment: Please don't add the details in comment but edit the question accordingly

Comment: in your Model `public function articles()` and NOT `public function article()`

Comment: Ya right ! thank you very much.

Comment: Even though this is a good question with a good code example, I've voted to close this due to it being caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `articles` relationship in your tag model is not defined. So when you call `Tag::where('name', request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->articles` you are not getting a Collection but getting `null`.

This is why you are getting this error as you can not loop over a `null` variable.

You should fix your relationship:

```
public function articles() // <---- You were missing the 's'
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says that the array of articles is empty.

You need to add the condition to check  the array is not empty.

```
@if(!empty($articles))
@foreach ($articles as $article)
@endforeach
@endif
```

And this is not the correct way to get articles. I recommend to you use whereHas to check tag.

Comment: `@forelse`/ `@empty` / `@endforelse` looks better and does the same 

Comment: I'm using data from database, and everything was working before i add the tag

Comment: Yes, @ChristopheHubert I appreciate your way. But For an explanation to OP, I used if like this.. otherwise, OP will be confuse about the what is forelse 

Comment: I tried to write @if(!empty($articles)) , a new problem appear

Comment: After you added this functionality, you are not getting articles as no tag matched to articles. that's why.. you need to  add the condition as I suggested or you can use `forelse`

Comment: And what is new problem?

Comment: The problem disappear, but it give me empty index page

Comment: The problem was in the eloquent ! thanks for helping